# My lwuit application is running slow on my Nokia x2 phone

Tags: mobile, java-me, lwuit, nokia

Why is my lwuit application running slowly on phones, and how can I fix it to perform better?

When I run the LwuitDemo, it is running fine. So maybe there is something missing in my code.

I use this when want to display a dialog:

```
 Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.show("Add User/Flux", "Please enter the pin", "Ok", null);
            }
        });
```

And when I want to create and show a form

```
System.gc();
```

Comment: I think the issue is on my lwuit ressource

Comment: When my I use the transparency on my form, Dialog or other field, the application is quite slow on my device not on a simulator, so I managed not to often using it or not using it at all... :)

Answer (score 0):

You must NEVER do that. Invoke and block opens a new thread while blocking the EDT which is the exact opposite of what you need to do.

You need to show dialogs on the EDT not the other way around e.g. using `callSerially/AndWait`.

Comment: Thanks Shai... I usually use callSerially but due of the issue I had I change my code many time in other to find out the solution. and I finally got the solution on the ressource.